# How to integrate Eslint with jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, eslint

How can I integrate ESLint with Jenkins?

Answer (score 58):

You need to export your [ESLint](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) report into an xml file and use any of the violation/lint reporter plugins that jenkins has available like [Checkstyle](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Checkstyle+Plugin), [Warnings](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin) or [Violations](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Violations) plugins.

For ESLint I personally prefer using the Checkstyle plugin in Jenkins.

So the way you could export your eslint reports into Jenkins is by doing the following:

1. From your Jenkins job's configuration screen, add a Build step of "Execute Shell"
2. Add the following command into it: `eslint -c config.eslintrc -f checkstyle apps/**/* > eslint.xml` (replace `apps/**/*` to the path of your app files)
3. Add a Post Build Action of "Publish Checkstyle analysis results" and input the path where your "eslint.xml" file got exported. (This is assuming you have installed the Checkstyle plugin in Jenkins)

Then, when you execute the job you will be able to see the ESLint report against the files it got executed.

---

Understanding what I have done with:

`eslint -c config.eslintrc -f checkstyle apps/**/* > eslint.xml`

- `-c config.eslintrc` this point into the `.eslintrc` configuration file and uses whatever we specify there to use. (Please see above ESLint link I've provided)
- `-f checkstyle` this will specify eslint what format it should use on the report, please see the available formats in this [link](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#f-format)
- `apps/**/*` this is the path of the files you would like for eslint to check (**/* is the pattern for any files and folder)
- `> filename` this is the export cli arg where the results are going to be stored each time the build is run

[image]

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

With the latest version of ESLint you can export the output into whatever file you'd like with the following command line argument:

`-o your_file.file_format`

Please refer to their [documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#o-output-file)

NOTE:

In the case that the invocation to eslint has errors, the command will return a value of `1`, and the build will be marked as *failed*, which is not necessarily wanted. To avoid this, append the following: `|| true`

Comment: I can't get it to work as you described because in my post build session the `publish checkstyle results` doesn't show up. Have an idea of what might be happening?

Comment: same here. But I saw it shows up under "Build Settings" where you have to check the box to activate it. But It doesnt give me an option to specify the xml file.

Comment: Build settings? hmm sounds like you have a different version of jenkins. What version do you have?

Comment: Alternatively, if you're using Jenkins pipelines, then you'd write `step([$class: 'hudson.plugins.checkstyle.CheckStylePublisher', checkstyle: 'src/ahl.com/dockit/static/eslint.xml'])` rather than the setting in the UI.

Comment: I cannot find config.eslintrc where it will be?

Answer (score 6):

For ESLint & Jenkins integration, you can use [Warnings Next Generation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng/) plugin.

An example for Multibranch Pipeline project would be:

```
stage('Install dependencies') {
        steps {
            echo 'Installing dependencies...'
            sh 'rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install'
        }
}
stage('Build') {
        steps {
            sh 'npm run build'
        }
}
stage ('Static Analysis') {
        steps {
            sh ' ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js -f checkstyle src > eslint.xml'
        }
        post {
            always {
                recordIssues enabledForFailure: true, aggregatingResults: true, tool: checkStyle(pattern: 'eslint.xml')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From plugin [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin) on github:

> - **recordIssues** step scans for issues in a given set of files (or in the console log) and reports these issues in your build.

Comment: Should use `npm ci` *"This command is similar to npm install, except it's meant to be used in automated environments such as test platforms, continuous integration, and deployment -- or any situation where you want to make sure you're doing a clean install of your dependencies."* [ [npm-ci](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ci) ]