# How to integrate Jenkins and Eslint XML file?

Tags: jenkins, checkstyle, eslint

I've  recently found the question "[How to integrate Eslint with jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043227/how-to-integrate-eslint-with-jenkins)" and it seems great but it actually doesn't work as expected.

I've installed checkstyle with jenkins but it doesn't show up like this image:

[image: the way checkstyle was supposed to integrated with jenkins]

In the post-build actions section, it does not give me the possibility to insert my `eslint` xml file.

Is there another way I can get checkstyle to work decently with eslint and fail build every time eslint fails?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, contrary to the *Build Steps* the *Post-Build Actions* are still not sorted alphabetically in the respective dropdown list in Jenkins 1.625.1.

*Publish Checkstyle analysis results* is located at the very top of the list in my Jenkins after installing the [Checkstyle Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Checkstyle+Plugin).

See [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) to fail a build if a script doesn't succeed, i.e. if its return status is greater than zero.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes, I've seen that box but how do I integrate it to eslint and fail build once there's any warnings/erros?