# How to integrate eslint in angular with Jenkins build

Tags: angular, jenkins, eslint, checkstyle

I found a similar question here:

[How to integrate Eslint with jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043227/how-to-integrate-eslint-with-jenkins)

However, I have an angular project that uses ESLint for linting,
and start it via:

`npx ng lint projectname --format checkstyle > checkstyle-results.xml`

However, this also includes some non-xml output, so the result can't be parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `--silent` flag to your call:

```
npx ng lint projectname --format checkstyle --silent > checkstyle-result.xml
```